# Insert row into another table and update data

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

In Oracle SQL, I can select a row into another table

```sql
insert into TableA (select * from TableB b where b.id = 2);
```

However, `b.color = 'blue'` and I want to update it to red before the row gets inserted into `TableA` without having to select each column from `TableB`, I want to `select *`.

`TableA` does not have an id that matches `TableB`.

Comment: "I want to select \*"   -  OK, **why**? You apparently already know that the correct solution is to specify your columns by name (and to hard-code 'red' for `color`) but you are asking to do it in some other way. It will be hard to help you if you don't explain *why* you don't want to use the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your select into a temp table (which you will have to create) then update your temp table to red then insert it back to A

```
  INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE 
  Select * from TableB b where b.id = 2

  Update temp_table
  Set color = 'Red'

  Insert into TableA (Select * from Temp_table)
```

Comment: What does `b.color` represent in your second statement (the `update`)? Hint: there is no "b" in that statement - which is why I ask.

Answer (score 0):

*"I want to select *"*

does not make sense because you do NOT want to select *.  If you did then you would want red not blue as the color.

You can hack around this using a trigger, eg

```
trigger BLAH 
before insert on A
for each row
begin
  :new.color := case when :new.color = 'blue' then 'red' else :new.color end;
end;
```

but man..I cannot tell you what a bad bad idea that would be.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
insert into TableA(col1, . . . , color, . . . coln)
     select . . . , (case when color = 'blue' then 'red' else color end), . . .
     from TableB b
     where b.id = 2;
```

Whether you like it or not, it is best practice to list all the columns both for the `insert` and the `select`, particularly for code that may be run more than one time.

If you find it too hard to list out the columns (using either a spreadsheet or SQL query), you can do the update *afterwards*:

```
insert into TableA
     select *
     from TableB b
     where b.id = 2;

update TableA
    set color = 'red'
    where color = 'blue' and id = 2;
```

This is approximate, because you might already have rows in the table, but it gives an idea.